# How to allow iframe request to specific sites only using .htaccess apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iframe

**What I have:**
I have an apache2 server running  on my computer. I am serving it via https://api.*somedomain*.com by portforwarding. I also have another website https://www.*samedomain*.com running on 3-party hosting.

```
somedomain.com and samedomain.com are same domains. 
It's just an example.
```

**Expected:**

1. I want to allow iframe requests from https://www.*samedomain*.com only. Or any other subdomain.
2. I want to block all the (iframe) request from other sites.
3. Writing must be done within *.htaccess*

**Reasons**

1. I want certain pages from api.*samedomain*.com to be shown on www.*samedomain*.com

**End notes**

Thanks for your help. I am really grateful. (In advance)

I want to allow iframe request from specific sites (in my case, only from my subdomains). All the other requests will be blocked.